# Client seeing different version of page. Issues with Centering

Tags: html, css, wordpress, centering

I'm having a few issues with a site I'm working on for a client which launched today. On my machine and my iphone everythings looks to spec, but on their machines they're seeing many issues.

there machine
[image: there machine]

my machine
[image: my machine]

there machine
[image: there machine]

my machine
[image: my machine]

I've tried clearing my browser cache, and I don't have any caching plugins on the wordpress so I'm not sure why I don't see the issues she is having. We're both using safari on macs as well.

It seems like there is an issue with centering. Can anyone figure out what's going on? I'm in a bit of a bind.

Heres the landing page

```
<div class="homepagewrap" id="portbgimage1" style="background-image: url('<?    php the_field('MC_homepagebackground'); ?>');">
    <div class="borderin">
        <div class="logohome">
            <a href="<?php bloginfo('url');?>/portfolio/"><img src="<?php     the_field('homepage_logo'); ?>"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
<div class="customfooter">
617-227-5343  ∙  <a     href="mailto:info@mcarterandco.com">info@mcarterandco.com</a>
</div>
```

and css

```
.homepagewrap{
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
position: relative;

height:100vh;
box-sizing: border-box;
border: 20px solid rgba(0,0,0,0);
}


.logohome{
box-sizing: border-box;
padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.logohome img{
max-width: 80%;
margin-left: 10%;
}
```

the second page

```
<div class="portwrap" id="portwrap1">
<div class="portwrapchild" id="portwrapchild1">
<a href="<?php bloginfo('url');?>/newclassic/"><span class="porttitles"     id="porttitles1">The New Classic</span></a>
</div>
<div class="portbgimage" id="portbgimage1" style="background-image: url('<?php     the_field('portupload1'); ?>');"></div>
</div>

<div class="portwrap" id="portwrap2">
<div class="portwrapchild" id="portwrapchild2">
<a href="<?php bloginfo('url');?>/artful-mix/"><span class="porttitles"     id="porttitles2">The Artful Mix</span></a>
</div>
<div class="portbgimage" id="portbgimage2" style="background-image: url('<?php     the_field('portupload2'); ?>');"></div>
</div>

<div class="portwrap" id="portwrap3">
<div class="portwrapchild" id="portwrapchild3">
<a href="<?php bloginfo('url');?>/historic-home/"><span class="porttitles"     id="porttitles3">The Historic Home</span></a>
</div>
<div class="portbgimage" id="portbgimage3" style="background-image: url('<?php     the_field('portupload3'); ?>');"></div>
</div>

<div class="portwrap" id="portwrap4">
<div class="portwrapchild" id="portwrapchild4">
<a href="<?php bloginfo('url');?>/escape/"><span class="porttitles"     id="porttitles4">The Escape</span></a>
</div>
<div class="portbgimage" id="portbgimage4" style="background-image: url('<?php     the_field('portupload4'); ?>');"></div>
```

and accompanying css

```
.portwrap{
position: relative;
float: left;
width: 50%;
height: 50%;
background-size: cover;
}

.portbgimage{
width:100%;
height:100%;
}

#portwrap1{
border-top: 20px solid #E0E0E0;
border-right: 10px solid #E0E0E0;
border-bottom: 10px solid #E0E0E0;
border-left: 20px solid #E0E0E0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
#portwrap2{
border-top: 20px  solid #E0E0E0;
border-right: 20px solid #E0E0E0;
border-bottom: 10px solid #E0E0E0;
border-left: 10px solid #E0E0E0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

#portwrap3{
border-top: 10px solid #E0E0E0;
border-right: 10px solid #E0E0E0;
border-bottom: 20px solid #E0E0E0;
border-left: 20px solid #E0E0E0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

#portwrap4{
border-top: 10px solid #E0E0E0;
border-right: 20px solid #E0E0E0;
border-bottom: 20px solid #E0E0E0;
border-left: 10px solid #E0E0E0;
box-sizing: border-box;
}


.portwrapchild {
/*overflow: hidden;*/
z-index:99;
text-align: center;
font-family: 'Crimson Text', serif;
font-style: italic;
font-weight: 200;
font-size: 3.5em;
color: #E0E0E0;
width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
}
```

Comment: Should we guess at the code?

Comment: Your client probably has a cached stylesheet. Also how to take a screenshot on your mac: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201361

Comment: @j08691 updated with the code

Comment: @cfreak I'm not certain it's on their end. I opened it up on a third parties device and the styling errors were consistent.

Comment: may be because their safari's version is old? for safari 8 -webkit- prefix is needed before transform, where ever you've used transform: translate add vendor prefix  '-webkit-' like this  -webkit-transform: translate (this will work for safari and chrome). Check this link out for other browsers http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing much else besides the small snippets of code you provided, you have not included browser-specific prefixes that make things work in older versions of different browsers.

So something like

`-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
 box-sizing:border-box;`

would possibly help. Be sure to put the prefixes before the non-prefixed version, and to apply to other CSS attributes you are using that also need prefixes, like `transform` and `background-size:cover`